# Como retornar a pagina anterior luego de subir una foto (sin perder los datos)

Tags: php

Me estoy complicando con algo que estimo sera simple pero mi inexperiencia hace que me encuentre empantanado. 
Tengo una pagina donde subo una noticia, es muy simple, tan simple que puedo subir una única foto.
[image: un boton para subir la imagen]

```
<form action="subir.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="ui segment">
                    <input type="text" name="archivo_final" value="<?php echo $proxima; ?>" hidden> 
                    <input class="ui button" type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">
                    <input  type="text" name="nombre_peli">
                    <input class="ui blue button" type="submit" name="subir" value="Subir imagen">
                </div>
            </form>
```

el boton SUBIR tiene ese código.
Ahora bien, en el archivo subir.php cuando se produce la subida del archivo al servidor, coloco este codigo:

```
if (!file_exists($ruta)){
   $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);
   if ($resultado){
      header('Location: nueva_noticia.php');
      //echo "El archivo se ha movido exitosamente.";
   } else {
      echo "Ocurrió un error al mover el archivo.";
 }
 } else {
   echo $_FILES['imagen']['name'] . ", este archivo existe";
 }
```

el problema que tengo es que cuando todo sale perfecto, ese "header" me devuelve a la pagina anterior, pero si ya tenía cargada la noticia, me borra todo, es como que carga todo desde cero... 
No se si me conviene crear una función php y retornar el resultado de la función...

PD: antes tenía un plugin phpupload que encontré por ahi pero no quiero agregar mas cosas extras que terminan complejizando el proyecto. es más, uso semantic y no hay una forma de poner un boton de subir imagen que quede prolijo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bueno amigo la cosa es sencilla para lo que buscas que entendí podrías hacer algo sencillo como : [image: el código es sencillo para tu uso]
[image: la otra parte del código]

Comment: Hola Jaime sería más ùtil agregar el texto del código, incluso no se ve completamente el código en las imagenes. Además considera agregar una explicación del mismo. Revisa [tour].

Comment: lo siento es que aún soy algo nuevo y no se como poner el código, me disculpo.

Comment: No te preocupes al contrario gracias por ayudar a otros usuarios, para editar o agregar más contenido a tu respuesta, da clic en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/95074/edit) , ahí puedes pegar el código

Comment: gracias muy amable, dale lo haré mejor a la próxima, es no se hacer que el código quede como el chico que publico la pregunta.